# How to store user data in browser more securely?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, local-storage

I'm working on a project where I'm verifying admin and user from the backend. I have a database and there is a collection called admins. I stored my admin's email there and when a user will log in if the user's email is available in the database it will return isAdmin true or else it will return false. so that's how I can give the admin special access. But the problem is I'm storing my user information in the local storage so every time when the user opens the browser I can get his info without login him. so I have to also store isAdmin true or false in the local storage. If anyone edits the local storage he can get access to the admin panel. I want to know how can I make it more secure or how can I store isAdmin more securely so that no one can edit it from the client-side?

Comment: Research secure/httponly cookies, they are mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Answer (score 1):

so ideally you shouldn't really solve these issues on frontend side of application but on API (backend, db, whatever you use). Only this that should be somehow saved on frontend (client) is user's token and with every request to API you should include this token and backend should be responsible for authorisation of request.

Simple example:

1. user logs in to api
2. api responds with auth token - 'abcd1234'
3. client saves this token to local storage / cookie
4. in next calls you include this token to request
5. GET /all-users { headers: { Authorisation: 'abcd1234' } }
6. API reads this token, decides if owner of this token is authorised to access these data

It's not this simple in real life, but you should understand a little.

And now solution to your problem - i suggest you to do none of this, but for school project its okay i guess

1. store your role in some hash so user doesn't know what is under the hash and can't simply guess admin hash
2. use some UUID instead of role - basically same as 1.
3. store your role in some global variable - so this way users can't see them in localStorage or cookies -- but its on client so its accessible to everyone in source code